# What is the value of $ g (x + f (y)) $?

Tags: functions, proof-verification, contest-math

Let $ f, g: \mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R} $ function such that $ f (x + g (y)) = - x + y + 1 $ for each pair of real numbers $ x, y $. What is the value of $ g (x + f (y) )$?

Solution:
[image]

Correct?

Comment: I haven't checked your work, but given the contest math tag, if you are in a time crunch, any solution has to be consistent with all solutions, and the solutions $f(x)=1-x$, $g(x)=-x$ work, so $$g(x+f(y))=-x-f(y)=-x-(1-y)=-x+y-1$$This process is clearly not rigorous, but can point you in the right direction!

Comment: @DonThousand Why should any solution be consistent with this?

Comment: How did you see that $ g (0) = 0 $?

Comment: If two valid solutions are inconsistent in output, then the question is not well-defined. They wouldn't ask you a question that isn't well defined. Again, this is meant as a tool to gain insight, nothing more.

Comment: What you have done is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn’t make out all that you did, but the start is certainly promising.  Using $x \to x-g(0), y \to 0$, you get from $f(x+g(y))=-x+y+1$:
$$f(x-g(0)+g(0)) = -x+g(0)+1 \implies f(t) = f(0)-t, f(0) = g(0)+1$$

$$\therefore -x+y+1 = f(x+g(y))=f(0)-x-g(y) \implies g(t)=g(0)-t$$
$$\implies g(x+f(y))=g(x+f(0)-y)=g(0)-x-f(0)+y=-x+y-1$$